# Problems converting a char to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've written following code & im trying to search this table for rows between a specific period:

```
SELECT 'RWH' + P.Hospital_Number AS MRN,
       P.Date_of_birth, 
       pd.Clinic_date AS Date_Seen,  
       pd.Clinic_type_No
FROM (Patient_diabetes AS pd 
INNER JOIN Patients AS p ON pd.Patient_No = p.Patient_No) 
INNER JOIN Staff AS s ON pd.Seen_by1_No = s.Staff_No
WHERE (((pd.Clinic_type_No)=241))
--AND hospital_number like '%63028%'
AND CONVERT(datetime,pd.Clinic_Date,121) BETWEEN '02/04/2015' AND '24/09/2015'
ORDER BY p.Date_of_birth,
pd.Clinic_date DESC
```

But I get the following error, any ideas how to fix this?:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2 The conversion of a char data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: what is the datatype of clinic_date?

Comment: The error message is very clear - You have some `pd.Clinic_Date` values that aren't correctly formatted in a way that SQL Server can convert them to `DateTime`.  This is exactly why you shouldn't store dates as `char`.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I know, the DB design is terrible - but i've picked it up from someone else and can't just go changing it...

Comment: What datatype and values are in `pd.Clinic_Date`?

Comment: You will have to either fix the data which can't be converted, or use `try_convert`, which will nullify the 'bad' data. `try_convert` is only available in sql server 2012+, sadly

Comment: No worries, I have used this to fix it: AND pd.Clinic_Date between '20150402' and '20150924'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change:

```
AND CONVERT(datetime,pd.Clinic_Date,121) BETWEEN '02/04/2015' AND '24/09/2015'
```

To this:

```
AND CONVERT(date,pd.Clinic_Date,121) BETWEEN '2015-04-02' AND '2015-09-24'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here in the `BETWEEN '02/04/2015' AND '24/09/2015'`

By default `'24/09/2015'` converts into `"mm/dd/yyyy"` format data. So there is no 24th month.

Try to explicitly point the format of string data:

```
BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'02/04/2015',103) 
    AND CONVERT(datetime,'24/09/2015',103)
```